# what would be the time complexity of DBSCAN algorithm?

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, clustering

what would be the time complexity of DBSCAN algorithm if we use it for graph(sparse) clustering $O(n^2)$ or $O(n \log{n})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the graph is sparse, if you have a data structure to query in $O(\log{n})$, you can reach to $O(n \log{n})$ for your case. More details in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN):

> DBSCAN visits each point of the database, possibly multiple times (e.g., as candidates to different clusters). For practical considerations, however, the time complexity is mostly governed by the number of regionQuery invocations. DBSCAN executes exactly one such query for each point, and if an indexing structure is used that executes a neighborhood query in $O(\log n)$, an overall average runtime complexity of $O(n \log n)$ is obtained (if parameter $\varepsilon$ is chosen in a meaningful way, i.e. such that on average only $O(\log n)$ points are returned). Without the use of an accelerating index structure, or on degenerated data (e.g. all points within a distance less than $\varepsilon$), the worst case run time complexity remains $O(n^2)$. The distance matrix of size $(n^2-n)/2$ can be materialized to avoid distance recomputations, but this needs $O(n^2)$ memory, whereas a non-matrix based implementation of DBSCAN only needs $O(n)$ memory.